# Are these models equivalent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

> **Main question:** I define the same model in two different ways. Why do I get different results? They seem to be the same model.

Secondary question (answered below) If I run the code again, I get different results again. I have set the seed at the beginning to fix the randomness. Why is that happening?

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

model1= Sequential([
     Dense(20, activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', 
               input_shape=(2,)),
     Dense(2,  activation='linear', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'),
])

model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

ipt    = Input(shape=(2,))
x      = Dense(20, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(ipt)
out    = Dense(2,  activation='linear',  kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
model2 = Model(ipt, out)

model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

x_train=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[3,4]])

model1.fit(x_train, x_train,epochs=2, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False)
model2.fit(x_train, x_train,epochs=2, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False)
```

The first time, the output is:

```
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 68ms/step - loss: 14.4394 - val_loss: 21.5747
Epoch 2/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 502us/step - loss: 14.3199 - val_loss: 21.4163
Train on 2 samples, validate on 1 samples
Epoch 1/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 72ms/step - loss: 11.0523 - val_loss: 17.7059
Epoch 2/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 491us/step - loss: 10.9833 - val_loss: 17.5785
```

The second time, the output is:

```
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 80ms/step - loss: 14.4394 - val_loss: 21.5747
Epoch 2/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 501us/step - loss: 14.3199 - val_loss: 21.4163
Train on 2 samples, validate on 1 samples
Epoch 1/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 72ms/step - loss: 11.0523 - val_loss: 17.6733
Epoch 2/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 485us/step - loss: 10.9597 - val_loss: 17.5459
```

---

**Update after reading the answer:** By the answer below, one of my questions has been answered. I changed the beginning of my code to:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
import random
random.seed(2)
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(3)
```

And, now I am getting the same numbers as before. So, it is stable. But, my main question has remained unanswered. Why at each time, the two equivalent models give different results?

Here is the result I get every time:

**results 1:**

```
Epoch 1/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 66ms/sample - loss: 11.9794 - val_loss: 18.9925
Epoch 2/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 268us/sample - loss: 11.8813 - val_loss: 18.8572
```

**results 2:**

```
Epoch 1/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 67ms/sample - loss: 5.4743 - val_loss: 9.3471
Epoch 2/2

2/2 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/sample - loss: 5.4108 - val_loss: 9.2497
```

Comment: I had experienced similar problem 2 years ago, although I had set the three level seeds, and in the end, I abandoned Keras for that reason and switched to pure TF. There was also a similar complain somewhere else.  Not sure if the problem is solved by now.

Comment: @entropy Thanks for the comment. Can you answer my first question as well? Why at every time the two identical models defined in two different ways yield different answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem's rooted in the *expected vs. actual* behavior of model definition and randomness. To see what's going on, we must understand how "RNG" works:

- A "random number generator" (RNG) is actually a function that produces numbers such that they map onto a probability distribution 'in the long run'
- When the RNG function, e.g. `RNG()` is called, it returns a "random" value and *increments its internal counter by 1*. Call this counter `n` - then: `random_value = RNG(n)`
- When you set a SEED, you set `n` according to the value of that seed (but not *to* that seed); we can represent this difference via `+ c` in the counter
- `c` will be a constant produced by a non-linear, but deterministic, function of the seed: `f(seed)`

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(4)         # internal counter = 0 + c
print(np.random.random()) # internal counter = 1 + c
print(np.random.random()) # internal counter = 2 + c
print(np.random.random()) # internal counter = 3 + c

np.random.seed(4)         # internal counter = 0 + c
print(np.random.random()) # internal counter = 1 + c
print(np.random.random()) # internal counter = 2 + c
print(np.random.random()) # internal counter = 3 + c
```

```py
0.9670298390136767
0.5472322491757223
0.9726843599648843

0.9670298390136767
0.5472322491757223
0.9726843599648843
```

Suppose `model1` has 100 weights, and you set a seed (`n = 0 + c`). After `model1` is built, your counter is at `100 + c`. If you *don't* reset the seed, even if you  build `model2` with the *exact same code*, the models will differ - as `model2`'s weights are initialized per `n` from `100 + c` to `200 + c`.

---

**Additional info:**

There are *three* seeds to ensure better randomness:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)         # for Numpy ops
import random 
random.seed(2)            # for Python ops
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(3)     # for tensorfow ops - e.g. Dropout masks
```

This'll give pretty good reproducibility, but not perfect if you're using a GPU - due to parallelism of operations; [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ys8ofBeR2kA) explains it well. For even better reproducibility, set your `PYHTONHASHSEED` - that and other info in the official [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development).

"Perfect" reproducibility is rather redundant, as your results should agree within .1% majority of the time - but if you really need it, likely the only way currently is to switch to CPU and stop using CUDA - but that'll slow down training tremendously (by x10+).

---

**Sources of randomness**:

- Weight initializations (every default Keras initializer uses randomness)
- Noise layers (Dropout, GaussianNoise, etc)
- [Hashing](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2280#issuecomment-306959926) for hash-based operations, e.g. item order in a set or dict
- GPU parallelism (see linked video)

---

**Model randomness demo**:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4)

model1_init_weights = [np.random.random(), np.random.random(), np.random.random()]
model2_init_weights = [np.random.random(), np.random.random(), np.random.random()]
print("model1_init_weights:", model1_init_weights)
print("model2_init_weights:", model2_init_weights)
```

```py
model1_init_weights: [0.9670298390136767, 0.5472322491757223, 0.9726843599648843]
model2_init_weights: [0.7148159936743647, 0.6977288245972708, 0.21608949558037638]
```

Restart kernel. Now run this:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4)

model2_init_weights = [np.random.random(), np.random.random(), np.random.random()]
model1_init_weights = [np.random.random(), np.random.random(), np.random.random()]
print("model1_init_weights:", model1_init_weights)
print("model2_init_weights:", model2_init_weights)
```

```py
model1_init_weights: [0.7148159936743647, 0.6977288245972708, 0.21608949558037638]
model2_init_weights: [0.9670298390136767, 0.5472322491757223, 0.9726843599648843]
```

Thus, flipping the order of `model1` and `model2` in your code also flips the losses. This is because the seed does not reset itself between the two models' definitions, so your weight initializations are totally different.

If you wish them to be the same, reset the seed before defining EACH MODEL, and before FITTING each model - and use a handy function like below. But your best bet is to restart the kernel and work in separate `.py` files.

```py
def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    tf.set_random_seed(3)
    print("RANDOM SEEDS RESET")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but still, answers are different at different runs (they give similar results after a few runs). Also, my main question is about why the models give answers at each run?

Comment: @Albert See updated answer; for your particular case, you should get near-perfectly reproducible results if you set all three seeds - so if you really run the same code twice and get results that differ by more than 0.1-0.05%, something is off (unsure what)

Comment: @Thanks. Can you answer the other part of my question as well? Why at each time, two models yield different answers?

Comment: @Albert I have, in my previous comment and in my answer under "Sources of randomness"; the question now is, _how different_ are your results if you use all three seeds? For example, what's the average % difference in losses that you're seeing? -- (Also, use "@"username (without quotations) to notify users of your reply)

Comment: First of all, I read online and it seems that the numpy seed has to be set before tensorflow is imported. So, I have done this at the beginning of my code:   import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
import random
random.seed(2)
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(3)

Comment: Now, it is stable. Can you update your answer? I have suggested an edit.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have given the numbers.

Comment: @Albert Unsure I understand - you say "now it is stable", and "here is the result I get _every time_" - in other words, the two models' results are no longer different?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I get result1 for my first model, and I get result2 for my second model. result1 is not equal to result2 (see above). But, result1 does not change if I rerun the code. Also, result2 does not change if I rerun the code.

Comment: @Albert It'd help if you explicitly labeled "Result1" and "Result2" in your question, as there are now 3-4 separate loss windows, and I cannot discern which is which. Also, I just noticed you have two different model codes - in the future, it'd help labeling them `model1` and `model2`, as latter also came first

Comment: @Albert Try removing `Activation('linear')` from your `Sequential` model - see if the models begin to agree

Comment: Thanks. I have marked what I mean by result1 and result 2.

Comment: After I removed the Activation('linear') from your Sequential model, they did not agree. The same as before. I wouldn't expect a change with removing that since linear is just bypassing the activation. BTW, if you copy and paste the code you can see how different they are on your machine.

Comment: @Albert A very interesting case, originally went over my head per question formatting -- answer updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You mean the seed changes after each use?

Comment: When I make two separate *.py files and set three random seeds as suggested by your answer, I get very similar results. especially, if I run the codes multiple times, I can see although the answers change, I get just a few different possible results. Still, I am not sure what happens in a single py code that the results are not similar. Even when I set the numpy seed before each line, the same thing happens.

Comment: @Albert Numpy seeds alone won't be enough - set _every_ seed before building the model. Here, try [this](https://pastebin.com/8HGwxZVC)

Comment: @Albert And the seeds don't change (but something else does) - see updated answer