# Tensorflow LSTM stateful option not maintaining state between batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am new to Tensorflow and wanted to understand the [keras LSTM layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) so I wrote this
test program to discern the behavior of the `stateful` option.

```py
#Tensorflow 1.x version
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

NUM_UNITS=1
NUM_TIME_STEPS=5
NUM_FEATURES=1
BATCH_SIZE=4

STATEFUL=True
STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES=True

lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=NUM_UNITS, stateful=STATEFUL,
            return_state=True, return_sequences=True,
            batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIME_STEPS, NUM_FEATURES),
            kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='ones',
            recurrent_initializer='ones')
x = tf.keras.Input((NUM_TIME_STEPS,NUM_FEATURES),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
result = lstm(x)

I = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.run(I)

X_input = np.array([[[3.14*(0.01)] for t in range(NUM_TIME_STEPS)] for b in range(BATCH_SIZE)])
feed_dict={x: X_input}

def matprint(run, mat):
    print('Batch = ', run)
    for b in range(mat.shape[0]):
        print('Batch Sample:', b, ', per-timestep output')
        print(mat[b].squeeze())

print('BATCH_SIZE = ', BATCH_SIZE, ', T = ', NUM_TIME_STEPS, ', stateful =', STATEFUL)
if STATEFUL:
    print('STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES = ', STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES)

for r in range(2):
    feed_dict={x: X_input}
    OUTPUT_NEXTSTATES = sess.run({'result': result}, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT_NEXTSTATES['result'][0]
    NEXT_STATES=OUTPUT_NEXTSTATES['result'][1:]
    matprint(r,OUTPUT)
    if STATEFUL:
        if STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES:
            #For TF version 1.x manually re-assigning states from
            #the last batch IS required for some reason ...
            #seems like a bug
            sess.run(lstm.states[0].assign(NEXT_STATES[0]))
            sess.run(lstm.states[1].assign(NEXT_STATES[1]))
        else:
            lstm.reset_states()
```

Note that the LSTM's weights are set to all ones and the input is constant for consistency.

As expected the script's output when `statueful=False` has no sample, time, or inter-batch
dependence:

```
BATCH_SIZE =  4 , T =  5 , stateful = False
Batch =  0
Batch Sample: 0 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 1 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 2 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 3 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch =  1
Batch Sample: 0 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 1 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 2 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 3 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
```

Upon setting `stateful=True` I was *expecting* the samples within each batch to yield different outputs (
presumably because the TF graph maintains state between the batch samples).  This was not the case, however:

```
BATCH_SIZE =  4 , T =  5 , stateful = True
STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES =  True
Batch =  0
Batch Sample: 0 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 1 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 2 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 3 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch =  1
Batch Sample: 0 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
Batch Sample: 1 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
Batch Sample: 2 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
Batch Sample: 3 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
```

In particular, note the outputs from the first two samples of the same batch are identical.

**EDIT**: I have been informed by [OverlordGoldDragon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10133797/overlordgolddragon)
that this behavior is expected and my confusion is in the distinction between a *Batch* -- a collection of
`(samples, timesteps, features)` -- and *Sample* within a batch (or a single "row" of the batch).
Represented by the following figure:

[image]

So this raises the question of the dependence (if any) between individual samples for a given batch.  From the
output of my script, I'm led to believe that *each* sample is fed to a (logically) separate LSTM block -- and
the LSTM states for the difference samples are independent.  I've drawn this here:

[image]

**Is my understanding correct?**

As an aside, it seems the `stateful=True` is broken in TensorFlow 1.x because if I remove the explicit
assignment of the state from the previous batch:

```py
         sess.run(lstm.states[0].assign(NEXT_STATES[0]))
         sess.run(lstm.states[1].assign(NEXT_STATES[1]))
```

it stops working, i.e., the second batch's output is identical to the first's.

I re-wrote the above script with the Tensorflow 2.0 syntax and the behavior is what I would expect
(without having to manually carry over LSTM state between batches):

```py
#Tensorflow 2.0 implementation
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

NUM_UNITS=1
NUM_TIME_STEPS=5
NUM_FEATURES=1
BATCH_SIZE=4

STATEFUL=True
STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES=True

lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=NUM_UNITS, stateful=STATEFUL,
            return_state=True, return_sequences=True,
            batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIME_STEPS, NUM_FEATURES),
            kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='ones',
            recurrent_initializer='ones')
X_input = np.array([[[3.14*(0.01)]
                     for t in range(NUM_TIME_STEPS)]
                     for b in range(BATCH_SIZE)])
@tf.function
def forward(x):
  return lstm(x)

def matprint(run, mat):
    print('Batch = ', run)
    for b in range(mat.shape[0]):
        print('Batch Sample:', b, ', per-timestep output')
        print(mat[b].squeeze())

print('BATCH_SIZE = ', BATCH_SIZE, ', T = ', NUM_TIME_STEPS, ', stateful =', STATEFUL)
if STATEFUL:
    print('STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES = ', STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES)

for r in range(2):
    OUTPUT_NEXTSTATES = forward(X_input)
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT_NEXTSTATES[0].numpy()
    NEXT_STATES=OUTPUT_NEXTSTATES[1:]
    matprint(r,OUTPUT)
    if STATEFUL:
        if STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES:
            pass
            #Explicitly re-assigning states from the last batch isn't
            # required as the model maintains inter-batch history.
            #This is NOT the same behavior for TF.version < 2.0
            #lstm.states[0].assign(NEXT_STATES[0].numpy())
            #lstm.states[1].assign(NEXT_STATES[1].numpy())
        else:
            lstm.reset_states()
```

This is the output:

```
BATCH_SIZE =  4 , T =  5 , stateful = True
STATEFUL_BETWEEN_BATCHES =  True
Batch =  0
Batch Sample: 0 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 1 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 2 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch Sample: 3 , per-timestep output
[0.38041887 0.663519   0.79821336 0.84627265 0.8617684 ]
Batch =  1
Batch Sample: 0 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
Batch Sample: 1 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
Batch Sample: 2 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
Batch Sample: 3 , per-timestep output
[0.86686385 0.8686781  0.8693927  0.8697042  0.869853  ]
```

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969065/tensorflow-best-way-to-save-state-in-rnns?rq=1) question is related ... I don't quite understand the accepted answer tho ...

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491737/understanding-keras-lstms-role-of-batch-size-and-statefulness?rq=1) does a good job explaining the role of the samples within a batch.  It seems each sample within a batch should be a time-delayed version of the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything appears to be working as intended - but the code's in need of much revision:

- `Batch: 0` should be `Sample: 0`; your `batch_shape=(4, 5, 1)`, contains 4 *samples*, 5 *timesteps*, and 1 *feature* / *channel*. `I` in your case is the actual batch marker
- Each sample is treated as an *independent sequence*, so it's like first feeding sample 1, then sample 2 - except during learning, batch sample losses are averaged to compute the gradient
- Each one of your samples is *identical* - so it's sensible to get identical outputs for each batch; run `print(X_input)` to verify
- Stateful works as intended: given the *same* input, `stateful=False` yields *same* outputs (because no internal state is maintained) - whereas `stateful=True` yields *different* outputs for different `I`, even though the inputs are same (due to memory)
- As-is, your `lstm` is *not* learning, so weights are the same - and all `stateful=False` outputs will be exactly the same for same inputs
- Initializing all weights to the same value is strongly discouraged - instead, use a [random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210700/are-these-models-equivalent/58210853#58210853)

Comment: I agree, my understanding of the Samples vs Batch was off.  But this now raises a question of the relationships between the different samples within a given batch.  I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the ``X_inputs`` are intentionally identical -- I did this because I was initially expecting for the output for *each* sample to be different because I thought each sample wasn't treated independently.  Yup, there is no learning or weight adaptation going on, I didn't care really what the weights are for this, just that they are the same between each Sample/Batch so I could get an understanding of the behavior.

Comment: @rmccabe3701 Nice drawings, and there is an answer - but you're now extending the question beyond its original scope (which is against the rules, but more importantly - it'd stand a lot clearer as a separate question). You can ask it as a new question and '@' mention me - I'll gladly answer

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll definitely have a follow up question. I'll mark this one as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @OverLoardGoldDragon: it seems this @-based mention doesn't work.  Here is my follow up question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276337/proper-way-to-feed-time-series-data-to-stateful-lstm

Comment: @rmccabe3701 Got the message now; strange it didn't work on your question. I'll get around to it.

Comment: @rmccabe3701 I suggest you put your first bold question toward bottom, as answering it fully can occupy an entire question - but I will provide an answer with reference material. In a nutshell, "yes", but it also greatly matters what exactly you _think_ that pic depicts. The rest of the question's well-formulated and I'll answer in full