# Keras: Getting different accuracy using model.train_on_batch() and model.fit(). What could be the reason and how to fix that?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have two identical models with same parameters. Both of these are trained on MNIST dataset. First one is trained using model.fit() and the second one is trained using model.train_on_batch(). The second model is giving less accuracy. I want to know what could be the reason for that and how to fix it?

**Data preperation:**

```
batch_size = 150
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

**MODEL 1:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

***MODEL 1 ACCURACY:***

> Test loss: 0.023489486496470636 Test accuracy: 0.9924

**MODEL 2:**

```
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model2.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(Dropout(0.25))
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model2.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size2 = 150
epochs2 = 12
step_epoch = x_train.shape[0] // batch_size2

def next_batch_train(i):
  return x_train[i:i+batch_size2,:,:,:], y_train[i:i+batch_size2,:]

iter_num = 0
epoch_num = 0
model_outputs = []
loss_history  = []

while epoch_num < epochs2:
  while iter_num < step_epoch:
    x,y = next_batch_train(iter_num)
    loss_history += model2.train_on_batch(x,y)

    iter_num += 1

  print("EPOCH {} FINISHED".format(epoch_num + 1))
  epoch_num += 1
  iter_num = 0 # reset counter


score = model2.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

***MODEL 2 ACCURACY:***

> Test loss: 0.5577236003954947 Test accuracy: 0.9387

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Four sources of difference:

1. `fit()` uses `shuffle=True` by default, this includes the very first epoch (and subsequent ones)
2. You don't use a random seed; see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210700/are-these-models-equivalent/58210853#58210853)
3. You have `step_epoch` number of batches, but iterate over `step_epoch - 1`; change `<` to `<=`
4. Your `next_batch_train` slicing is way off; here's what it's doing vs what it needs to be doing:

   - `x_train[0:128] --> x_train[1:129]   --> x_train[2:130]   --> ...`
   - `x_train[0:128] --> x_train[128:256] --> x_train[256:384] --> ...`

To remedy, you should include a shuffling step in your `model2`'s train loop - or use `fit` with `shuffle=False` (not recommended). Also, a tip: `64, 128, 256, 128, 64` Conv2D filters is a pretty bad arrangement; what you're doing is *upsampling* greatly, in a sense "fabricating data" - if you're going to use more filters, also increase their `strides` proportionally so that the total tensor size between the layers remains ~same (or less).

All mentioned fixes + updated seed function below; run it for 1 epoch, 12 takes too long - if 1 works so will 12. Can keep your original model if you'd like, but I recommend testing with one below, as it's significantly faster.

---

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
        tf.random.set_seed(3)
    else:
        tf.set_random_seed(3)
    print("RANDOM SEEDS RESET")
```

```py
reset_seeds()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```py
def next_batch_train(i):
  return (x_train[i*batch_size2:(i+1)*batch_size2,:,:,:], 
          y_train[i*batch_size2:(i+1)*batch_size2,:])

iter_num = 0
epoch_num = 0
model_outputs = []
loss_history  = []

while epoch_num < epochs2:
  while iter_num < step_epoch:
    x,y = next_batch_train(iter_num)
    loss_history += model2.train_on_batch(x,y)

    iter_num += 1

  print("EPOCH {} FINISHED".format(epoch_num + 1))
  epoch_num += 1
  iter_num = 0 # reset counter

score = model2.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

---

**Better alternative: use shuffling**

```py
class TrainBatches():
    def __init__(self, x_train, y_train, batch_size):
        self.x_train=x_train
        self.y_train=y_train
        self.batch_size=batch_size

        self.indices = [i for i in range(len(x_train))]
        self.counter = 0

    def get_next(self):
        start = self.indices[self.counter] * self.batch_size
        end   = start + self.batch_size
        self.counter += 1
        return self.x_train[start:end], self.y_train[start:end]

    def shuffle(self):
        np.random.shuffle(self.indices)
        print("BATCHES SHUFFLED")
```

```py
train_batches = TrainBatches(x_train, y_train, batch_size)

while epoch_num < epochs2:
  while iter_num <= step_epoch:
    x, y = train_batches.get_next()
    loss_history += model2.train_on_batch(x,y)

    iter_num += 1

  train_batches.shuffle()
  train_batches.counter = 0
  print("EPOCH {} FINISHED".format(epoch_num + 1))
  epoch_num += 1
  iter_num = 0 # reset counter
```

Note that this won't guarantee your results will agree with `fit()`, as `fit()` may shuffle differently (even with a random seed) - but the implementation is in fact correct. Above also doesn't shuffle at the first epoch (easy to change).

Comment: " if 1 works so will 12." Can u explain a little on that?

Comment: @UmairJavaid Meaning, if `fit` and `train_on_batch` produce same results in 1 epoch, they'll produce same results in 12 epochs also (assuming `shuffle=False`) - so no need to take the long route

Comment: can u tell me how i can train this model on tpu in google colab?

Comment: can u look at my other question

Answer (score 0):

One difference between those two models that I noticed is that in your second model, you didn't shuffle your training data after each epoch. `.fit()` will shuffle your training data in default.

Comment: Will .fit() shuffle data in every batch?

Comment: @UmairJavaid No, it will shuffle the data in each epoch.

Comment: could u please try that and see if that is the root cause